# gps speed of device

Tags: ios5, cllocationmanager

I am calculating the speed of a device for this i have used delegate method

`(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`

but when I test it on a device it is not showing speed instead it always shows zero speed.

code used is

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{        
    NSLog(@"\nStarting point=%@",startingpoint);
    if (self.startingpoint == nil)
    {
        self.startingpoint = newLocation;
        oldLocation=self.startingpoint;
    }
    //Calculate speed
    double gpsSpeed = newLocation.speed;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are checking that the speed is 0?

Comment: i just showed gpsspeed into a label like this
`label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",gpsSpeed];`

Comment: when i print it shows -1.000000

Comment: It says here that a negative number means an invalid speed. Perhaps you're not moving fast enough or it hasn't got a good enough signal to work out your speed.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed

Comment: but i m calculating speed for pedestrian....so a small changes are also reqired...
and secondly i m also not getting the distance..

Comment: How are you calculating the distance? Have you checked that newLocation is not nil? Perhaps the GPS hasn't fired up yet, maybe you're only getting cell-tower based location and therefore it can't check your speed. If it isn't nil, check that it is in the right place.

Comment: i used following code ....
`
lbl1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    lbl2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
`
newlocation is not null...
and for distace i used
`CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:startingpoint];`